# rails slim template in js response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I'm using slim templates and need to write a js format response,
When I tried

```
javascript:
  alert('x');
```

code didn't run, I guess because it was wrapped in the `<script>` tag.

I found myself writing this

```
| alert('x');
```

It works, but, if I need to add another command I need to write

```
| alert...
= "\n"
| anotherCommand
```

Is there a better way to write this kind of things with slim templates?
My actual code looks very bad (here it is)

```
| UIkit.notification("booked");
= "\n"
| $("#total").html("
= escape_javascript(render "total")
|");

= "\n"
| $("#total_#{@id}").html("
= escape_javascript(render "total", order:@order)
|");
```

It's just 3 lines of js with html replaceing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just write all the commands under one `|` like this:

```
|
  UIkit.notification("booked");
  $("#total").html("#{{escape_javascript(render 'total')}}");
  $("#total_#{@id}").html("#{{escape_javascript(render 'total', order: @order)}}");
```

[Reference for `|`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Verbatim_text__).

[Interpolation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Text_interpolation) will also work, and you don't need to add `\n` explicitly, because the text under `|` is copied as is, and line breaks will also be copied. But your javascript will be valid even without them, because commands are separated with semicolon.

Note that here you need double braces for interpolation, because otherwise interpolation output will be html escaped.

Comment: 10x, is there a way to avoid the semicolon?

Comment: @ChenKinnrot For this particular case you can omit semicolons without modifying the code above, because the text under `|` is copied as is, so there will be line breaks. But why do you want to avoid them? Style guides [recommend to use them](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#semicolons).

Comment: @ChenKinnrot I added statement about line breaks to my answer.